# How do I install Entity Framework Core in an Azure pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, entity-framework-core, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have an existing pipeline to build and deploy my .NET 6 project to an Azure Web App using Azure SQL. Now I'm trying to add a step to run the Entity Framework Core migrations. I am using this article as a model https://blogit.create.pt/vini/2022/11/07/entity-framework-update-database-using-azure-pipelines/ because it's recent and more concise.

I tried installing EF Core with the `DotNetCore` command.

```
-task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Install EF tool'
  inputs:
    command: 'custom'
    custom: 'tool'
    arguments: 'install dotnet-ef --global --version 7.0.5'
```

This fails because it can't find or access (401 error?) the Azure Artifacts feed.

`Unhandled exception: NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types.FatalProtocolException: Unable to load the service index for source https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/OneHRADO/<removed the guid here>/_packaging/OneHRADO_PublicPackages/nuget/v3/index.json. ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).`

The URL its using matches with the `Connect to Feed` setting for Visual Studio
[image]

I'm not sure where its getting that URL because I've tried changing the setting in my `nuget.config` file but it doesn't change where the job is looking.

Next I tried using `DotNetCoreCLI` command with a feed Id.  I know the Feed Id in `vstsFeed` input is correct because I'm using it in a Nuget restore that runs before the build.

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Install EF tool'
  inputs:
    command: 'custom'
    custom: 'tool'
    arguments: 'install dotnet-ef -g --version 7.0.5'
    feedsToUse: 'select'
    vstsFeed: '<FeedId>' #actual Id removed
```

```
Starting: Install EF tool
==============================================================================
Task         : .NET Core
Description  : Build, test, package, or publish a dotnet application, or run a custom 

dotnet command
    Version      : 2.232.0
    Author       : Microsoft Corporation
    Help         : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/dotnet-core-cli
    ==============================================================================
C:\Windows\system32\chcp.com 65001
Active code page: 65001
Info: .NET Core SDK/runtime 2.2 and 3.0 are now End of Life(EOL) and have been removed 
from all hosted agents. If you're using these SDK/runtimes on hosted agents, kindly upgrade to newer versions which are not EOL, or else use UseDotNet task to install the required version.

"C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" tool install dotnet-ef -g --version 7.0.5
Unhandled exception: NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types.FatalProtocolException: Unable to load the service index for source https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/OneHRADO/<guid redacted>/_packaging/OneHRADO_PublicPackage/nuget/v3/index.json.
 ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).
at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()
at NuGet.Protocol.HttpSource.<>c__DisplayClass15_0`1.<<GetAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
```

I thought since the Nuget restore step was running, I'd try using the `NugetCommand`.

```
- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: 'Install EF tool'
  inputs:
    command: 'custom'
    arguments: 'install dotnet-ef -Version 7.0.5'
    feedsToUse: 'select'
    vstsFeed: '<FeedId>' #actual Id removed
```

It finds the feed and starts to install the package but errs for `Error NU5000: Package 'dotnet-ef 7.0.5' has a package type 'DotnetTool' that is not supported by project 'D:\a\1\s'` and rolls back.

```
Starting: Install EF tool
==============================================================================
Task         : NuGet
Description  : Restore, pack, or push NuGet packages, or run a NuGet command. Supports NuGet.org and authenticated feeds like Azure Artifacts and MyGet. Uses NuGet.exe and works with .NET Framework apps. For .NET Core and .NET Standard apps, use the .NET Core task.
Version      : 2.231.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/nuget
==============================================================================
C:\Windows\system32\chcp.com 65001
Active code page: 65001
Detected NuGet version 6.8.0.131 / 6.8.0+993ad4ee2350e33c7821d6609e0099971b534a6a.993ad4ee2350e33c7821d6609e0099971b534a6a
C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\NuGet\6.8.0\x64\nuget.exe install dotnet-ef -Version 7.0.5 -NonInteractive
Error NU5000: Package 'dotnet-ef 7.0.5' has a package type 'DotnetTool' that is not supported by project 'D:\a\1\s'.
```

Other than the Nuget command I just mentioned, everything I try ends in a 401 error.

UPDATE: I happened to search the artifact feed and it appears that `dotnet-ef` is already there?  I'm doing a `NuGet Restore`.  Shouldn't that install EF?  So I tried just running the command to generate the script

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Generate SQL Script'
  inputs:
    command: 'custom'
    custom: 'ef'
    arguments: 'migrations script --idempotent --project "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\HR Taxonomy Change Management"\*.csproj --output $(System.ArtifactsDirectory)\script.sql'
```

and it fails

```
Starting: Generate SQL Script
==============================================================================
Task         : .NET Core
Description  : Build, test, package, or publish a dotnet application, or run a custom dotnet command
Version      : 2.232.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/dotnet-core-cli
==============================================================================
C:\Windows\system32\chcp.com 65001
Active code page: 65001
Info: .NET Core SDK/runtime 2.2 and 3.0 are now End of Life(EOL) and have been removed from all hosted agents. If you're using these SDK/runtimes on hosted agents, kindly upgrade to newer versions which are not EOL, or else use UseDotNet task to install the required version.
"C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" ef migrations script --idempotent --project "D:\a\1\s\HR Taxonomy Change Management\*.csproj" --output D:\a\1\a\script.sql
Could not execute because the specified command or file was not found.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install EF Core, you can config [DotNetCoreCLI@2 - .NET Core v2 task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/dotnet-core-cli-v2?view=azure-pipelines) as shown below.  `feedsToUse` and `vstsFeed` are required when command = restore. There aren't such parameters when using other commands.

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'custom'
    custom: 'tool'
    arguments: 'install dotnet-ef -g --version 7.0.5'
```

Then we can see this tool is installed successfully and can invoke the tool using `dotnet-ef`.

[image]

---

Update:

Based on the current situation, it seems that you have added the Azure artifact as package sources in the `nuget.config` file. When you use `nuget.config`, dotnet.exe will download the required packages/tools from the `packageSources` defined in this file in your default working directory.

You are getting a 401 (Unauthorized) error because dotnet is trying to download `dotnet-ef` from your azure artifact, which requires authentication. To resolve this error, there are two workarounds for your reference.

**Workaround1**: Change the working directory when downloading `dotnet-ef`.

You can change the working directory when downloading `dotnet-ef` to a path that does not have the `nuget.config` file. At this point dotnet will download the required tool from the Microsoft NuGet feed by default. Change the DotNetCoreCLI@2 task as shown below.

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'custom'
    custom: 'tool'
    arguments: 'install dotnet-ef -g --version 7.0.5'
    workingDirectory: '$(Agent.BuildDirectory)'
```

**Workaround2**: Use `--ignore-failed-sources` parameter to bypass the error from the private feed and use the public Microsoft feed

Add public NuGet feed to the `packageSources` in your `nuget.config` file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <clear />
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
  </packageSources> 
</configuration>
```

Add `--ignore-failed-sources` parameter.

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'custom'
    custom: 'tool'
    arguments: 'install dotnet-ef -g --version 7.0.5  --ignore-failed-sources'
```

Based on my test, `--ignore-failed-sources` doesn't work when using .Net 8. If you are using `windows-2019` image to run your pipeline, there isn't any other change. Otherwise, add a UseDotNet@2 task before downloading to specify the .Net used in the pipeline to 7.x. See the software in the images from [image](https://github.com/actions/runner-images/tree/ubuntu22/20240116.3/images).

```
- task: UseDotNet@2
  inputs:
    packageType: 'sdk'
    version: '7.x'
```

Comment: That is the first thing I tried.  Sorry I missed this point in my question.  It can't find the Azure Artifacts feed.  I'll update the question with more specifics.

Comment: I also re-reviewed the documentation on the `DotNetCoreCLI` command: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/dotnet-core-cli-v2?view=azure-pipelines  and it is a little misleading.  It doesn't say that `FeedsToUse` is only used with `Restore` it just says its required.  Other commands they use working like `Use when...` so it implies it will work.

Comment: You can create a classic build pipeline and add a DotNetCoreCLI task from the UI. Then you can find that there isn't an option to specify the feed if the custom command is `tool`.  I can reproduce your issue. I have updated my answer with the root cause and the workarounds. Please check if it works for you.

Comment: I can't go directly to MS for the package, I have to use the private feed due to DevSecOps requirements.  Thankfully, option 1 worked.  Thank you for the detailed answer.